# AngularJS not displaying JSON response in view

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

UPDATED as requested with more info:

I have a controller that calls a web method and I want the returned JSON to be binded to a variable in the controller called applications. The alert displays the JSON correctly but I see nothing in my View.

Note I have tried $scope and 'this' in the controller with manual data and only 'this' worked which is why I have use it instead of $scope below.

```
app.controller('AppsController', function ($http, $scope) {
$http.post('/WebMethod/DoStuff', {}).
 success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     alert(data);
     this.applications = data;
 })
}
```

My View is like this

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppsController as appCtrl">
<div class="row" ng-repeat="application in appCtrl.applications">

<div class="col-xs-6 applicationName" ng-click="appCtrl.expand($index)">{{application.name}}</div>
</div></div>
```

JSON like

```
[
{
    name: "Application 1",
    alerts: "2",
    status: "Red",
    notifications:  [
        {
            header: "Notification Header 1",
            updateType: "New",
            message: "hello world",
            startTime: "11:00",
            endTime: "12:00"
        }              
    ],
    expanded: false
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not what you expect it to be. Try this:

```
app.controller('AppsController', function ($http, $scope) {
  var self = this;
  $http.post('/WebMethod/DoStuff', {}).
   success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       alert(data);
       //or you can use $scope.applications = data; instead 
       self.applications = data;
   })
}
```

See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for explanation of `this` in Javascript.

Comment: This worked, I also had to wrap my data in JSON.parse() for some reason. Thanks for the response, very helpful insight into 'this' via your link also which is why I chose this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `controllerAs` syntax, which means you don't place variables on the `$scope` in the controller, but rather on the controller instance itself.

Placing the data on `this` is correct, but you have to keep reference to the instance itself, so you need to do this:

```
app.controller('AppsController', function ($http, $scope) { // you probably don't need to inject the $scope
   var ctrl = this;
   $http.post('/WebMethod/DoStuff', {}).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);
        ctrl.applications = data;
   });
}
```